# Disjoint and independent events

Tags: probability, independence

Scenario 1: Suppose we flip a coin once. If we define event A as the coin landing on heads and we define event B as the coin landing on tails, then event A and event B are disjoint because the coin can’t possibly land on heads and tails. [Taken from here](https://www.statology.org/disjoint-vs-independent/)

In the scenario 1, any independent events are possible?

Comment: There are only two possible *outcomes*; heads, and tails. An *event* is a set of outcomes, and there are only four of those: neither heads nor tails; heads; tails; heads or tails. Are any two of those four events independent?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Show that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events such that neither $A$ nor $B$ have probability zero, then $A$ and $B$ can't be independent.

Comment: Give an example of independent events in the scenario mentioned

Comment: There are none. After we flip the coin once, the scenario ends. Suppose that we flip the coin and it lands on heads. Considering that we don't flip a second time, $P(B)$ changes from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $0$. That is, the occurrence of $A$ affects the probability of $B$ occurring. Similar logic shows that the occurrence of $B$ affects the probability of $A$ occurring. Therefore $A$ and $B$ are not independent. Since $A$ and $B$ are the only possible events in this scenario, this scenario contains no independent events.